Can a former assistant district attorney become the chief public defender in the same county
I was appointed a public defender and he use to work as the assistant district attorney  int the same county and has been running to become district attorney how can he be appointed to me

What specifically do think the issue is? Many defense attorneys started their career as prosecutors.

What do you think a runner-up for district attorney should do professionally, after the winner lets them go? Drive Ubers but with a law degree? You did not give a country, but it seems like barring them from the only job where a law degree is required seems overly harsh for losing an election.

@nvoigt There are actually quite a few jobs that require a law degree besides prosecutor and public defender.

A possible conflict of interest would be, if they had cases involving you, or maybe if in their campaign they made statements concerning cases like yours and how they think their handling needs to change.
Otherwise, a prosecutor normally is an attorney and they can switch between jobs requiring a law degree (attorney, prosecutor, judge) as long as the respective employer will have them. Given that attorneys can be their own boss if they don't want to be employed by somebody else, that seems to be a save bet.
I personally know people who started out as lawyers, became prosecutors, judge, did not like being judge, went back to prosecutors. I am pretty sure if they for whatever reason weren't prosecutor any more, they'd make amazing defense attorneys.
So if you think your assigned public defender is biased, you should look for a personal connection to your case. Not their former job. Everybody of relevance (bar association or your countries equivalent) has already agreed that this is allowed, or they would not be there.
